# Capturing host IP in VMWare

Tags: linux, ip, vmware

I'd like to know if it's possible to capture the HOST IP address in a Linux environment. Basically I'm running CentOS on VMWare and I'd like to see which physical server my operating system is running on. I had a look and it seems it's not possible, however if someone has any ideas, I'd be glad to hear them.

Ta muchly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the host isn't behind some NAT and has access to the Internet, you could pull up a webpage that return you the IP address, like [What Is My IP Address](https://www.whatismyip.com/).

Otherwise, from the VMWare website : [The VMs have no information about the system they are running on. This is by design and has security related reasons.](http://communities.vmware.com/thread/139353)

Comment: yeah. your second link is my answer. Quite unfortunate. Does anyone happen to know what the 'security related reason(s)' is/are?